# Why is snapshot.data.length deprecated?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase_auth 3.0.1, firebase_core 1.4.0, cloud_firestore 2.4.0.
When I try to get data from firestore data.length and data[index].get("name") keeps on getting deprecated. Please help.

```html
Future getMenus() async{
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("products").get();

    return qn.docs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
      future: getMenus(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          print("ye");
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"])
              );
            }
          );
            // CustomText(text: "data", size: 20, colors: black, weight: FontWeight.bold);

        }
        else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(
            child: Text("Loading...")
          );
        }
        else{
          print("no");
          return CustomText(text: "No", size: 20, colors: black, weight: FontWeight.bold);

        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your `snapshot.data` is a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`.
To access data of a document, you can do this:

```dart
final docs = snapshot.data;

final data = snapshot.data.elementAt(index).data();

print(
  data['name'],
);
```

Comment: data[index] is deprecated

Comment: Use .elementAt like shown in post. (I edited it)